# ui sref not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular ui router and routing my pages, here my main page is contracts.html

I want to route to another page from this page hence I have written the following code. But it is not working, please take a look at the following code :

```
<li role="menuitem"><a ui-sref=".monthlysettings" onclick="$('#simple-btn-keyboard-nav2').text('PDC Settings')">PDC Settings</a></li>




.state('contracts', {
      url: '/contracts',
      controller: 'contractsController',
      templateUrl: 'contracts.html'
  }).state('contracts.monthlysettings', {
      url: '/monthlysettings',
      controller: 'monthlysettingsController',
      templateUrl: 'monthlysettings.html'
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state name should be the full name `contracts.monthlysettings`

```
<li role="menuitem"><a ui-sref="contracts.monthlysettings" onclick="$('#simple-btn-keyboard-nav2').text('PDC Settings')">PDC Settings</a></li>
```

Comment: Tried it, not working even after using the full name.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? Can you remove the onclick and see if it is working?